# How to set package variable using -ldflags -X in Golang build

Tags: go

I am creating an app using Go 1.9.2 and I am trying to add a version string variable to it using the `ldflags -X` options during the build.

I've managed to set a `Version` variable in my `main` package by using: `-ldflags "-X main.Version=1.0.0"`, however what I really need is to set the `Version` variable inside my `config` package instead of the `main` one. Is this possible?

Here is my build command:

`go build -ldflags "-X config.Version=1.0.0" -o $(MY_BIN) $(MY_SRC)`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Quoting from doc of [Command link](https://golang.org/cmd/link/):

> ```
> -X importpath.name=value
>     Set the value of the string variable in importpath named name to value.
>     Note that before Go 1.5 this option took two separate arguments.
>     Now it takes one argument split on the first = sign.
> ```

So it can be used for any package, not just for the `main` package. But you must specify the full *import path*, not just the package name.

E.g. if your `config` package is located at `$GOPATH/src/my/package/config`, then use the following command:

```
go build -ldflags "-X my/package/config.Version=1.0.0" -o $(MY_BIN) $(MY_SRC)
```

Comment: Do this only works if the specified package is under GOPATH or GOROOT?

Comment: @Muddz it also works for modules, but you have to use the full module name. So e.g. module `example.com/module` subdir `config` would be `example.com/module/config`, and you can use `-X example.com/module/config.Version=1.0.0` (only the last `.` seems to decide the separation between `importpath` and `name`).

Comment: The docs for `-X` have been updated since this answer was made, and add an additional caveat now: "This is only effective if the variable is declared in the source code either uninitialized or initialized to a constant string expression. -X will not work if the initializer makes a function call or refers to other variables."

Answer (score 24):

Add your (unitialized string) variable, build your binary, then do a

```
go tool nm <your binary> | grep <your variable>
```

it will display something like

```
101aa3820 B <import path>/config.Version
```

That’s the import path you’re looking for, to set in

```
go build -ldflags "-X <import path>/config.Version=1.0.0" -o $(MY_BIN) $(MY_SRC)
```

Comment: ```go tool: no such tool "rm"```

Comment: @TravisBear oh sorry, it’s a typo, it should be `nm`.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a simple example, hopefully it would clarify and help how to do it easily:

Create a directory for your application:

```
$ mkdir app && cd app
```

Create a sub directory `config`:

```
$ mkdir config
```

Add the following file. it should be under `app/config/vars.go`:

```
package config

var Version string 

var BuildTime string 
//todo: can add as many as build vars
```

In the root `app/`, add main package `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "app/config"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("build.Version:\t", Version)
    fmt.Println("build.Time:\t", build.BuildTime)
}
```

Now it is time to build:

`go build -ldflags "-X 'app/config.Version=0.0.1' -X 'app/config.BuildTime=$(date)'"`

Once it's built, you can run now the app:

```
$ ./app 
Version:     0.0.1
build.Time:  Sat Jul  4 19:49:19 UTC 2020
```

Finally, you may need sometimes to explore what does specific app you didn't code yourself provide in `ldflags`, you can do this by using `nm` that comes with `go tool` to list all `ldflags`.

Just build the app then use `go tool nm` to list all linker flags.

```
$ go build -o app 
$ go tool nm ./app
```

Still have any questions or anything to be more clarified? please feel free to leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: go tool nm for the win! great share!