# Debugging issues with -X ldflag

Tags: go

I have a go program like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var version string

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Version %s\n", version)
}
```

I would like to change the value of **version** at compile time, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354518/golang-application-auto-build-versioning?rq=1), so I'm building it in this way (wtf.go is in src/wtf):

```
go build -ldflags "-X wtf/main.version=1.0.0.1234" wtf
go install wtf
```

But when I run, **version** is an empty string.

I have tried various casings of **version**, different variations of the package name and path. It seems that **go build** does not validate the package/variable name very much, as clearly bogus ones do not generate an error.

Is there a way I can find out what variable go is trying to modify so that I can troubleshoot this?

I'm using Go v 1.10.3 for Windows/amd64.

Comment: Have you tried building without the "wtf/" prefix for the import path? e.g. `go build -ldflags "-X main.version=1.0.0.1234" wtf`

Comment: @ssemilla, one of the first things I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that you have to specify the package by import path, not relative folder to the `src` folder. So simply refer to your `version` variable like `main.version`. For details, see [How to set package variable using -ldflags -X in Golang build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509272/how-to-set-package-variable-using-ldflags-x-in-golang-build/47510909#47510909).

So navigate to `%GOPATH%/src/wtf`, and build it with the following command:

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.version=1.0.0.1234" wtf.go
```

(Or if you don't have source files with other packages in the `src/wtf` folder, you can leave out the source file name.)

This will place the `wtf.exe` in the current folder. Running it will print:

```
Version 1.0.0.1234
```

Note that `go install` is not needed. That will build your app and place the executable binary in `%GOPATH%/bin`, but that won't have the `version` set!

If you want to use `go install`, you again have to provide the flags. Run the following command in the `%GOPATH%/src/wtf` folder:

```
go install -ldflags "-X main.version=1.0.0.1234"
```

Also note that `go install` does not require you to run `go build` prior, and you do not need to run `go install` after `go build`. For details, see [What does go build build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612611/what-does-go-build-build/30612612#30612612)

Comment: Navigating to that location seems to work! I'm actually trying to do this from VS Code using the Go plug-in, so I guess I need to figure out how to get that information into the go.buildFlags config setting.