# how to generate or change code in compile time?

Tags: go

I want to add some code to start of function.
like

---

source code:

```
func A(){
    do something...
}
```

---

final code:

```
func A(){
    ADDED CODE
    do something...
}
```

---

I`m using **//go:generate** right now,but it will change the source code and should run it every function changed,so I wonder if there any way to do the job in compile time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set package variable using -ldflags -X in Golang build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509272/how-to-set-package-variable-using-ldflags-x-in-golang-build)

Comment: The code I want to add is a little complex, so the -X is not applicable to me

Answer (score 0):

What about using a function call to add code?

```
package mypkg

var extra = func() {}

func A() {
  extra()
  // ...do something
}
```

Then you can include or exclude an extra file to the same package:

```
package mypkg

func init() {
  extra = func() {
    // ADDED CODE
  }
}
```

You even could select from one ore more files with alternatives for the `extra()` function.

Answer (score -2):

> [H]ow to generate or change code in compile time?

You have to modify the compiler. (Don't do that.)

Comment: Not entirely true. You have the ldflag -X  with which you can set strings.